# Clear queue with filter function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery queue for which I would like to remove several elements. I cannot use a groupName for this, so ideally there should be a function that loops over each queued element, checks if it should be cleared, and then clears it.

How can I accomplish this?

I tried

```
$.each(queue, function(index, value) {}
```

But this doesn't loop over the queue elements.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by *queue*? Is it an animation queue, like `fx`? A jQuery object containing elements? Something else?

Comment: An ajax request queue:  queues.queue(doRequest);

Comment: I don't think it's part of jQuery Core, is that a plugin?

Comment: No, it's core. Normally it's used for animation queueing, but you can use it for anything. http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: I see. However, `queue()` can only queue operations, not elements, and does not expose the queued operations (unless you dig into internal details of jQuery). Can you post the code that queues your requests so we can determine the options you have?

Comment: I'm using this code to implement an ajax multi queue: https://github.com/GeReV/jQuery.ajaxMultiQueue/blob/master/jquery.ajaxMultiQueue.js - i want to be able to abort certain elements with certain conditions.

Comment: Looks like MultiQueue does not expose its internal structures either. However, it does return an abortable promise every time you call `queue()`. Perhaps you could accumulate these promises into an array of your own and iterate over that array to abort the ones you don't want. Of course, you would also have to store enough information in order to determine if you want a specific promise to continue running or not.

Comment: Frédéric, please add this as an answer so I can give you credit, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my comments, the MultiQueue plugin you're using does not expose the list of requests that are still pending. Its `queue()` method, however, returns an abortable promise for each request.

Therefore, you could maintain your own array:

```
var requests = [];
```

Populate that array with the promises returned by `queue()`, along with information you require in order to determine if each request should keep going or not:

```
requests.push({
    promise: queues.queue(doRequest),
    url: theUrlOfThatRequest,
    other: ["pertinent", "information"]
});
```

From there, you could iterate over that array and abort the promises you want:

```
$.each(requests, function(index, request) {
    if (shouldBeAborted(request)) {
        request.promise.abort();
    }
}
```

Note that you will also have to remove both successful and aborted promises from your `requests` array in order to keep it from growing too much and avoid processing promises multiple times. I left that as an exercise, as the right way to do that depends on the number of requests you issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I have implemented this, however, there seems to be an error. I get this: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jqXHR.abort(statusText)') -- seems like the jqXHR object does not have an abort method?

Comment: @Wesley, well, the source code of the plugin you linked to definitely injects an `abort()` method in all the promises it returns. It will be hard to know what's going wrong here without seeing more of your code.

Comment: The abort method of the promise is called correctly. It's the jqXHR's abort that is undefined. I console.log'd the jqXHR object and this is what it returns: http://i.imgur.com/IYgpQeB.png -- doesn't look like an XHR object.. Any idea what it is instead?

Comment: @Wesley, yes, it's a plain promise (built from a Deferred object). You cannot abort these. Are you perchance chaining your AJAX requests into `done()` or `then()` and passing the resulting promises to `queue()`?

Comment: I am doing : multiQueue.addRequest({ajaxOptions}).done(function({}); indeed.. How can I access the request this way?

Comment: @Wesley, you can't, `addRequest()` builds a jqXHR and chains it to `done()`, `fail()` and `then()` for its own purposes, so you will always be dealing with an unabortable promise if you call that method. That said, I'm not familiar with the plugin but I believe `addRequest()` is not supposed to be called directly from your own code, only indirectly through `queue()`.

Comment: addRequest is just the name of the method I added to the plugin based on your code (requests.push({..}) - So you are saying I cannot cancel this promise at all? Hmm... :(

Comment: @Wesley, ah, I mentioned that method based on one of your comments, so I guess it went full-circle :) In short, you should not call the `doRequest()` method of the plugin, only its `queue()` method, which returns abortable promises, which you can then abort.

Comment: Frédéric, sorry for all the questions. I am returning the promise in the addRequest method, you can see the code here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=x3D2fbEm - also note that I only pass ajax options to the multiqueue, which then creates it request in doRequest (differnet from addRequest!)

Comment: but I guess the doRequest method also has      .done(dfd.resolve)
     .fail(dfd.reject)
     .then(next, next);
 so it his a fault in the plugin itself?

Comment: @Wesley, I don't think so, from what I can analyze `doRequest()` is only meant to be used internally, so its making the jqXHR unabortable is not a bug, only an implementation detail.

Comment: Why does it include the jqXHR.abort() call then? Is it really not possible to abort it?

Comment: @Wesley, only through the promise that `queue()` gives back to you.

Comment: Well, I am doing request.promise.abort(), which executes the promise abort method, but then fails when it reaches jqXHR.abort()

Comment: @Wesley, you're absolutely right, I completely missed that `queue()` directly uses the unabortable jqXHR that `doRequest()` returns. So yes, the *proxy abort to the jqXHR if it is active* part of the plugin is bugged indeed. You won't be able to abort theses promises until that bug is fixed.

Comment: One last question; I want to now do it instead in the dorequest function (where I will check if the request should execute or not). How can I call .then (next, next) without the ajax call?

Comment: @Wesley, possibly with your own Deferred object, but that's too broad to be answered here -- I would suggest you post another question with all the appropriate context and the relevant parts of the plugin's source code.